# Linux/Debian server upgrading and Apache and MySQL servers installing

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mysql, debian-lenny

### Situation description

I have a linux server:

```
Distributor ID: Debian 
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 5.0.10 (lenny) 
Release:    5.0.10 Codename:    lenny
```

Lately, the MySQL server was a litte bit slow when trying to establish a connection to the databases, so I tried to restart the service with `service mysql restart` since then 2 things happened:

1. The service stops and refuses to be restarted once again
2. It displays an  error:

Once I try service mysql (start or restart or even stop)

```
error:tail: 
invalid option -- n
Try `tail --help' for more information.
tail: invalid option -- n
Try `tail --help' for more information.
```

`mysql start` gives:

```
ERROR 2002 Can't connect to local Mysql server through socket
/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (2)
```

But this file doesn't exist in any way in this directory. I though that maybe this file is located somewhere else in my server and the `my.cnf` just contains the wrong path and this is why the call fails. I tried to find the right path for the file: `mysqld.sock` and edit the required line in `my.cnf` file, but with find command I figure out there is no such a file `mysqld.sock` or `mysql.sock` in all the server directories.

In a next step I tried to re-install the MySQL server from scratch, what happened is that the old MySQL version and also Apache was successfully removed and the process for the installation was broken and failed to continue.

`php -v` shows the next output:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20060613/mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20060613/mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20060613/mysqli.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20060613/mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20060613/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20060613/pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.2.6-1+lenny16 with Suhosin-Patch 0.9.6.2 (cli) (built: Feb  3 2012 08:19:55)
Copyright (c) 1997-2008 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2008 Zend Technologies
with the ionCube PHP Loader v3.1.28, Copyright (c) 2002-2007, by ionCube Ltd.
```

### What I am trying to do now:

I made a backup for my websites located under `/var/www/vhosts` and I want to upgrade the system to Wheezy 7.0 Then to install Apache and MySQL what can I do in such a case, I don't even know if I still have my databases or they are already lost.

What steps are required to fix that?

Have to reconfigure after that the virtual host to enable my websites once again.

I am lost any help?

### EDIT:

To install mysql on debian Lenny I tried this:

```
aptitude -t lenny-backports install mysql-server-5.1 mysql-client-5.1 mysql-common
```

During the installation it displays that a connecxion test was faild, in the error log file:

```
mysql: error while loading shared libraries: libreadline.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: The socket file only exists when the mysql server is running, so don't panic over it not being on your disk. But please elaborate on `the installation was broken` in your re-install process. What errors do you get?

Comment: I closed the windows that contains the installation errors :(

Comment: Shouldn't you be starting the mysqld rather than mysql? Pretty sure but different distributions of MySQL may have it packaged differently, but at least for me on CentOS 6 mysql is the client, mysqld is the server.

Comment: I tied that too but the command loads for a log time and nothing happen ...

Comment: For the first time when that happend I tried mysqld_safe and it works fine, then after severals hours mysql service stoped once again and refused to be started even with mysqld or mysqld_safe

Comment: When you say you are upgrading Apache & MySQL, how are you doing it? Via package installers via `apt-get` or `aptitude`? Or via source or a binary downloaded elsewhere?

Comment: it stoped mysql server  service mysql stop then I typed $ sudo apt-get remove mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common this command made an error and the procedure was stoped... after that service  (mysql or apache2) status,start or whatever indicates there is no mysql server or apache

Comment: Why would you type in `sudo apt-get remove mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common` for an upgrade? I edited my answer below, but it seems like you trashed your system.

Comment: actually when I had trouble withmysql server I wanted to finish that by updating the version, as it is my first time to do that...I followed this [tutorial](http://xmodulo.com/2013/12/upgrade-mysql-server-debian-ubuntu.html)

Comment: That tutorial you linked to shows you how to install from source. If you have no idea how to to that then you are in over your head. I use Ubuntu to run many web servers & I simply use the package installers `apt-get` or `aptitude` to install the MySQL stuff. Unless you are doing something amazingly radical—which I can assure you, you are not—you are just messing up your Linux install by following random web site tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

Your server was compromised (as per previous question and also confirmed somehow with the strange behaviour of binaries like `tail` or others that were replaced).

So you have to do a clean re-install of everything; no commands can be trusted and they may not work properly as it seems to be happening. You should use a new server and install Linux and the rest of the stack (mysql, php etc) from scratch from repositories, or copy your data and code, wipe your current server and re-install.

Before that you want to try and figure out where the vulnerability was that they exploited so it doesn't happen again.

Also you want to test first in a server or investigate (ask, seach) if newer (current) versions of the stack (especially PHP) have backwards-incompatibility issues.

Comment: I aware oh this fact but for the moment I really need to make this server works again.. then I have to rebuilt every thing in a new server but in the meanwhile this server have to be reparaid(services have to work once again)

Comment: sorry but it may not be possible to "repair" your server without knowing exactly what the exploit did, which you may never know and thus a clean reinstall is the only way. Otherwise you'll probably just spend a lot of time going in circles. If you can't have a second server then copy your data out and clean-reinstall this one.

Comment: It’s not clear to me that the server is compromised as much as it is most possibly unintentionally screwed up thanks to a few other things as well.  Irregardless, you cannot repair a damaged system like this. There is a reason for security & patches.  And avoiding frustration like this is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

A few issues I see.  You say you did this:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

But are you logged in as root or a superuser?

Also, This error makes 100% no sense:

```
error:tail: 
invalid option -- n
Try `tail --help' for more information.
tail: invalid option -- n
Try `tail --help' for more information.
```

So are you trying to tail the MySQL log? And perhaps entered the tail command incorrectly? I would recommend doing this instead:

```
sudo tail -f -n 200 /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
```

**EDIT:** In your comments above, you say:

> $ sudo apt-get remove mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common this
>   command made an error and the procedure was stoped... after that
>   service (mysql or apache2) status,start or whatever indicates there is
>   no mysql server or apache

So you ran `sudo apt-get remove mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common`?  You completely removed MySQL from your system. Why would you do that if you are upgrading? Upgrading is an in-place process.

I would recommend you check if anything is in this directory which is where the actual MySQL binary files are stored:

```
ls -la /var/lib/mysql/
```

If anything is still there, I would do the following to retain that content:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/mysql/ /var/lib/mysql_BACKUP/
```

Then reinstall MySQL like this:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
```

Once reinstalled, stop the MySQL server like this:

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

Then shuffle the directories for the binary DBs like so to get the old DBs in place again:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/mysql/ /var/lib/mysql_FRESH_INSTALL_BACKUP/

sudo mv /var/lib/mysql_BACKUP/ /var/lib/mysql/
```

Comment: I am logged as root and this error make sence because in etc/init.d/mysql file in mysql call function there is a call to the tail with n parameter but once I tested tail with n in a command line it works fine

Comment: can I please give me the right command to reinstall MYSQL

Comment: Look at my latest edit. You run the same `apt-get` command you ran before, but use `install` instead of `remove`.

Comment: Ihave already did that but it displays the next:`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting mysql-server-5.0 instead of mysql-server
Package mysql-server-5.0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package mysql-server-5.0 has no installation candidate`

Comment: This the result of the command you gave to me..I tried in an another way could you please see the edit on the question